# How would the following image look like, if we didn't use $ct$ for time?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, coordinate-systems, dimensional-analysis

[image: Spacetime]

I just wonder how spacetime would look like if we didn't use $ct$ for $t$ and we just used $t$ instead?

I guess the $t$-axis would just scale. Would that mean that, the hyperbolas would be very hard for us to distinguish them from straight lines without zooming out too far? So is that a reason why using $ct$ is more convenient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What will happen depends on your units.

If you are using SI units, and use $t$ instead of $ct$, then you will effectively stretch the graph by an *enormous* factor such that the light cone will be extremely close to parallel with the $x$ axis. The hyperbolas in the top and bottom region of the graph would become very close to horizontal lines. The hyperbolas on the left and right hand side of the graph would be squashed into a tiny region that is hard to see. This corresponds to the way you would draw a spacetime diagram in Newtonian physics, where space and time are separate entities; stretching the diagram in this way is kind of a visual way of taking the Newtonian limit. (If you have solved problems with spacetime diagrams in special relativity such as the "pole in a barn" problem or the twin paradox, it is a fun exercise to take the solutions and stretch the pictures in this way to see how you recover the Newtonian solution to those problems, graphically).

If you are using natural units with $c=1$, then including $c$ or not including $c$ will not matter.

In general, if you are in units where $c$ is less than $1$, the graph will distort such that the light cone gets wider (the angle the light cone makes with the $y$ axis will be bigger) if you use $t$ instead of $ct$ on the $y$ axis. If you are units where $c$ is bigger than $1$, the light cone will appear narrower (angle between light cone and $y$ axis will be smaller).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I wonder if there is an interactive spacetime somewhere online where I can change values and see how that affects the overall graph! Is there such an online feature preferably one that I can even change ct to t in SI units and see how it looks like for myself? –

Comment: @Nuke I am not sure. If you know (or wanted an excuse to learn) a programming language like Python or Matlab, or know how to use Mathematica, this wouldn't be too difficult to code up and could be instructive!

Answer (score 1):

That is the same as setting c equal to 1, so the scale should not change at all. In general, yes, changing the units of c or t would just visually expand or contract the horizontal axis, equivalent to zooming in or out of that axis, which would make the light speed world line (ct=x) point at some angle other than 45°.  But if consistent units are used, nothing in the math should be any different.

Comment: Wait now im confused! If we change c from 299 792 458 to 1 the diagram won't change? How? Is there a picture of this spacetime where c = 1 and c = 299 792 458 so that I can see the differences? –

Comment: @nuke :  just keep the same picture and change the labels at the tick marks on the axes.

Comment: @Nuke the x-axis on the graph is scaled such that the line $dx/dt = c$ describes a 45 degree angle with the $ct$ axis, the pale grey lines on the graph. If you set $c =1$ then $ct = t$ and $dx/dt = 1$ is a 45 degree angle.

Comment: @Nuke if your $y$ axis is the product $ct$, then regardless of units chosen for time or distance the graph should look the same.  Choosing units where $c=1$ is not changing anything physical, it's just that for example, $t$ could be measured in years and $x$ in light years.

Comment: As another user said, it can be instructive to plot $t$ in seconds, say with axes from 0 to 10, and $x$ in meters from 0 to 1000 say, and see that the hyperbolas expand out to recover the Newtonian approximation, where time intervals are essentially constant for all world lines